# Connectivity graph for a digital model

Tags: software, ldd, bricklink, cad, ldraw

I'm looking for a way to take a digital representation of a model (e.g. an LDD or LDraw file) and extract from it a representation of the model that describes which pieces are actually connected to each other as a network graph. Bricklink Studio is able to calculate how many "detached sections" a model is comprised of (i.e. connected components) so this is definitely possible with available tools, I'm just not sure how to export this information in a format I could work with outside of Bricklink Studio.